# How do I say "uh-oh" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

I'm posting a lot of translation questions these days because I'm translating subtitles for a video. Some interjections have their specific Esperanto versions, like "ho" for "oh" (Swedish åh). 
Do we have some way to translate "uh-oh", as it is used in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uh-oh)?

Answer (score 4):

Neniu el la ekkriaj vortetoj listigitaj en PMEG kaptas tiun signifon, do oni verŝajne devas enkonduki novan ekkrian vorteton por ĉi tiu celo. Mi persone uzus *o-o!* (kun glotfermo inter la du *o*-oj aludita per la streketo, kaj kun akĉento sur la unua *o* kaj pro tio kun streketo anstataŭ spaceto). Ĝia sono estas pravigebla kaj per la angla *uh-oh!* kaj per la germana *oh oh!*.